# Class property array, can't use $this to set value

Tags: php, class, object, instantiation

In the class below, when instantiated, I receive the following error:

'$this' (T_VARIABLE) in your code on line 12
'default_timestamp' => $this->_time,

I'm confused because when the object is instantiated, I assume $_time is accessible for use, however it appears its not. I also tried `'default_timestamp' => time()`, but that threw an error as well. Am I misunderstanding object instantiation?

```
class DateTimeHandler {

    public $_date;
    public $_time = 'xxx';
    public $_datetime;
    public $_timezone;

    public $opts = array(
        'default_timezone' => 'America/New_York',
        'default_timestamp' => $this->_time,
        'formats' => array(
            'date' => 'Y-m-d',
            'time' => 'g:ia',
            'full' => 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
        )
    );

    public function __construct() {
        echo '<pre>', print_r( $this->opts, true );
    }

}

$d = new DateTimeHandler();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To initialize class members with dynamic value you can't do it directly. Instead  use `__construct` for same

```
class DateTimeHandler {

    public $_date;
    public $_time = 'xxx';
    public $_datetime;
    public $_timezone;

    public $opts = array();



    public function __construct() {

      $this->opts = array(
        'default_timezone' => 'America/New_York',
        'default_timestamp' =>time(), //OR $this->_time
        'formats' => array(
            'date' => 'Y-m-d',
            'time' => 'g:ia',
            'full' => 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
        )
    );

        echo '<pre>', print_r( $this->opts, true );
    }

}

$d = new DateTimeHandler();
```

Comment: That worked, is there a reason you cannot do it directly?

Comment: refer this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php **initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.**